# Get ClaimsPrincipal from bearer access token in custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I can get bearer access token from embedded authorization server.

The problem is when I request resource from WebAPI, I could not get back the ClaimsPrincipal based on the access token sent along.

**Below is the Http post: (1)**

```
GET /api/v1/courses/categories HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer QoHxP-MbGna2ekhZl-zV9C_3gW2LPBbe-i7DQDp1DFF0BGurjAsqx-rShhmTZlnvScnAdZHNnR1PLcVVuz8B3VwvsYwKKvp-tYw3sohf4B2m5IH97FeCRbA9_nv4DflZtUSSQnrdlKNHHQGgl8VZ5Pcdc09V5hAv5f3sGd-1qsIsKuON81mhlC2PKWNA6a0NTid_LyvzEY1zGQtrgx8ue2NFMNztXBYuy1jXgv6SPAdoOLU3mH38wXg4l7UmVJ10MAbcljNczDSgY9QOC439BmpscG_kIYONiqQaMGMQhmFqnaKIkCMy9PgQ9WvQaLpz
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bd0096e6-3471-bb49-460d-f198f7f516e4
```

**Below is the Owin Startup: (2)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

**Below is the WebAPI configuration: (3)**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.SuppressHostPrincipal();
        config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First().SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

**Grant access token: (4)**

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(context.Validated());
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType); // using Bearer
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccountId", Guid.NewGuid()));
        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

**Lastly here is the problem part: (5)**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // I tried to access the - ((ClaimsPrincipal)actionContext.RequestContext.Principal).Claims
    }
}
```

I tried to access the ClaimsPrincipal, but was empty, I need the "AccountId" which was set during GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() - look code at **(4)**.

Comment: var claimPrinciple =(ClaimsPrincipal)actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;

Comment: yes, I tried to access with code as you stated, please look at (5). The problem is the "claimPrinciple.Claims" don't have any record.

Comment: I host the WebAPI using IIS.

Comment: have you added any claims?

Comment: please look at (4), there is where I add new claim.

Comment: Yes i have just noticed that.

Comment: You need to check if user authenticated before fetching the claims in OnAuthorization?

Comment: at authorization server, when the user get the access token, user has been successfully authenticated. when user requests for resources using the access token, you mean i have to authenticate the user again at authentication filter before going in authorization filter?

Comment: if (claimPrincipal != null || claimPrincipal .Identity.IsAuthenticated){} check what it returns? put this in your OnAuthorization see what IsAuthenticated returns.

Comment: at OnAuthorization(), when request comes in, actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

Comment: i comment out the following code at (3), config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication(); config.SuppressHostPrincipal();, working fine now, Solved!